# Why can't I import from dir above?

Tags: python

I have the following structure

```
pacakgeName/
  utils.py
  folder1/
    coderunning.py
```

I want to import utils in coderunning.py by

```
from .. import utils
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I don't understand why?? Thank you for any help.

Utils.py has a

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
```

Does this change anything?

Comment: Relative imports depend on how you're running the project. If you're running the project from working directory `pacakgeName` (sic), then you can relative import up to (but not past) that folder. If you're running the project from `folder1`, then you can't use `..` to import things outside of that directory.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)??

Comment: Those `__future__` imports are not needed. Or do you really still run Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

I believe appending the directory where the stuff you want to import is to sys.path will make your life easier. In addition, you need an `__init__.py` file in the packageName for Python to recognize it as a package.

Happy Coding!

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('PATH OF packageName')
from packageName import utils
```